# Design/Architecture for a 'content editors' Java EE 6 web app

Tags: jakarta-ee, architecture, jsf-2

**[Rev.02: Due to no answers for Rev.01, let me please re-specify my question]:**

For a Java EE web app_ with *JSF 2.x frontend* the following URLs shall be in place:

1. Initially (static case, and as treated in thousands of book examples):

   - `www.acme.org/app/`
   - `www.acme.org/app/index.jsf`
   - `www.acme.org/app/contact.jsf`
   - `www.acme.org/app/about.jsf`
   - `www.acme.org/app/provider-registration.jsf`
   - `www.acme.org/app/login.jsf` 
     differs between sys-admin and provider-admin and redirects a sys-admin to:
   - `www.acme.org/app/sys-admin-console.jsf` 
     and a provider-admin to the `admin-console.jsf` listed below.
2. Later on (i.e. dynamically created and activated, and the aspect that's unclear to me):

   - `www.acme.org/app/providerName/`
   - `www.acme.org/app/providerName/index.jsf`
   - `www.acme.org/app/providerName/contact.jsf`
   - `www.acme.org/app/providerName/login.jsf`  for provider-admin and provider's customers
   - `www.acme.org/app/providerName/admin-console.jsf`
   - `www.acme.org/app/providerName/pageX.jsf`

   where `providerName` is an arbitrary name chosen by the provider and verified+granted by the system, and `pageX` is one or more pages created and arbitrarily named by each provider independently.
3. The "system realm" will know about the roles "sys-admin" and "provider-admin", whereas each "provider realm" will know about "provider-admin" and "customer" roles.

**My questions now are:**

1. From within the initial FacesServlet, what must I do to get these "sub-realms" (sub-JSF-webapps) running and the one or more Servlet(s) working well (together)?
2. How do I impose the access control rules?
   (a) By a dynamically deployed but static Servlet security config? or 
   (b) By an internal security component at app-level instead of servlet/web-container level?

I'd be very thankful for any help or any link to examples treating this problem. 
Natalia.

Comment: Please, really nobody that can show or point me at some possibilities to achieve such a more dynamic use case in JSF 2.0??? One of the main issues here is, how to dynamically publish a new .xhtml file (generated from a page spec in the backend db) into a sub-folder/sub-context in the app's exploded document root (on GlassFisch 3), so that the new page can be dispatched to the client like any other regularly/statically deployed JSF page. Any ideas? Thanks a lot in advance.